# How to get the list of devices that are attached with ONVIF(IP Camera) device?

Tags: onvif

I have a requirement to get the list of devices that actually getting the video streaming from ONVIF IP camera.
Is there a way to get it from ONVIF IP Camera Considering security aspects?
Also, I want to understand what kind of information I can get from ONVIF?

Answer (score 0):

Check §5.12.3 and §5.12.4 of [media service 2](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/media/ONVIF-Media2-Service-Spec.pdf). For Profile T devices, the topics

- `tns1:Monitoring/Profile/ActiveConnections`
- `tns1:Monitoring/ActiveSessions/VideoEncoder`
- `tns1:Monitoring/ActiveSessions/AudioEncoder`
- `tns1:Monitoring/ActiveSessions/AudioDecoder`
- `tns1:Monitoring/ActiveSessions/Metadata`

seem to be what you are looking for.